# Html button element click fails on IOS8

Tags: jquery, html, ios

I have just knocked up a simple site to support the NHS in the current corona virus pandemic and I'm getting reports from iPhone users that the buttons (Yes and No on the main page) are not clickable.

I have tried forcing `cursor: pointer` on the element as well as detecting if `touchstart` or `click` is available bu to no avail. Unfortunately I dont have an iPhone myself to test it on.

Any help would be great - all code (there really isnt a lot!) can be found at [https://stayhomeforthenhs.co.uk](https://stayhomeforthenhs.co.uk/)

Comment: The buttons are not working for me in any browser, desktop or mobile. You have an `onclick` attribute on those elements with no value. That will be causing issues and needs to be removed. Also note that those buttons are not contained in a form so clicking them will do nothing, unless you have som JS event handlers attached to them

Comment: Also note that you have an error with the FingerPrint2 library

Comment: The buttons are not supposed to be in a form, their click events are bound using JQuery in a rather standard way. The onlick has now been removed it was there to try and fix this problem (from the net).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan which browser did you try? its working fine in IE and chrome? I also dont get an errors reported in Chrome dev tools

Comment: Ah hang on - if fingerprintjs fails then yes the buttons will stay disabled because it needs fingerprintjs to actually post the data - can you share the fingerprintjs error?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 80 on Win10. Here's the console output I get https://i.imgur.com/7mnfO4F.png

Comment: The buttons are now disabled on my end, so that's the latest issue

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately in your case the download of fingerprint2js is blocked by the client so I cant do a lot about that I'm afraid. I have,however worked out the problem. It's to do with permissions in Facebook webview which I've fixed with a prompt

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is with Facebook permissions and how they effect the webview. If your facebook is set to not allow location the webview doesn't prompt for geolocation permission so it was falling into a bug whereby it didn't work when permission was denied.